# BeautifulSoup: how to keep HTML entity, &qout;

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

From https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters, it says

> If you give Beautiful Soup a document that contains HTML entities like
> “&lquot;”, they’ll be converted to Unicode characters:
>
> soup = BeautifulSoup("&ldquo ; Wow!&rdquo ; he said.", 'html.parser')
>
> str(soup)
>
> '“Wow!” he said.'

Is there any way to modify this behavior and make it preserve entities like **'&dlquo ;'**, **'&rdquo ;'** or **'&quot ;'** in string processing with BeautifulSoup for html or xml?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try reading the rest of that documentation section? You can get the entities back by passing `formatter="html"` to `soup.encode`:

```
>>> soup.encode(formatter="html")
b'&ldquo; ; Wow!&rdquo; ; he said.'
```

Another way is to replace `&` with `&amp;` before passing to BeautifulSoup:

```
>>> html = "&ldquo ; Wow!&rdquo ; he said."
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html.replace("&", "&amp;"), 'html.parser')
>>> print(soup.get_text())
&ldquo ; Wow!&rdquo ; he said.
```

Comment: I tried, but it did not work for '&qout ;'

Comment: Doesn't your second method mean that the in-memory representation of the document is malformed...means something different after your replacement? The other options are just dealing with external representation, but don't change the actual object, right?

Comment: & for &amp; is interesting.  The text property or get_text() returned the entity converted string which results preserving the original format.   It works, but may cause not-so-readable code.